# why required field validation not working in form using react?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-final-form, final-form

hi I am doing form validation using `react-final-form`.I also take help from this example
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/field-level-validation?from-embed
I am trying to do same thing when I click `submit` button it will show `Required` error if the field is required.

currently, in my demo, it is not showing this

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hellman-65dy3

```
<RFField
    component={SForm.Input}
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    placeholder="Please Enter full Name"
    required={true}
    validate={required}
/>
```

is there any way to show required message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is available as a prop, but you actually need to setup the mark-up to display the `required` message.

You can restructure your `SForm` like this to have it work with `semantic-ui` and `react-final-form`.

```
  <SForm.Group widths="equal">
    <RFField
      label="Name"
      name="name"
      validate={required}
    >
      {({ input, meta }) => (
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <SForm.Input {...input} type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
          {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
        </div>
      )}
    </RFField>
    <RFField
      label="last Name"
      name="lastName"
      validate={required}
    >
      {({ input, meta }) => (
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <SForm.Input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
          {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
        </div>
      )}
    </RFField>
  </SForm.Group>
```

See working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-shtern-s1pgj

Comment: in codesandbox you used `input` field not `SForm.Input`

Comment: Oh it probably just needs to update. As I'm seeing it now, it is using `SForm.Input`

Comment: @user944513 I threw on some extra-styling on there because it looks like the original gets lost when we use this format. Let me know if that helps.